# NSScrollView causes weird blurring when scrolled

Tags: objective-c, scroll, nsscrollview

I have an NSTextView inside an NSScrollView. On Snow Leopard, all was fine, however in Lion, when I try and scroll the view it looks something like this:

[image]

What is going on? How do I fix this? I've tried setting `[textView setDrawsBackground:YES]` and `[scrollView setDrawsBackground:YES]`, but neither seemed to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set `CopiesOnScroll` off, which I did in the Interface Builder.